# ImportError: cannot import name cbook

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 123, in <module>
    from . import cbook
ImportError: cannot import name cbook
```

I didn't find a solution, can anyone help?

Comment: I was able to fix this issue using this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46651581/importerror-cannot-import-name-cbook-when-using-pycharms-profiler

Comment: try fixing cbook, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623376/importerror-cannot-import-name-cbook

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**1.** Try to update `matplotlib`

```
python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

**2.** Try to reinstall `matplotlib`

```
python -m pip uninstall matplotlib
python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

What does the following snippet print to the console?

```
python -c "import matplotlib"
```

Comment: I have this import error too.  I am using conda package manager.  I tried uninstalling and installing and that didn't solve it.  `python -c "import matplotlib"` produces `ImportError: Matplotlib requires six>=1.10; you have 1.9.0`.  Then `conda update six` solved the problem.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I have the same issue using matplotlib. I have tried reinstalling matplotlib and ran `python -c "import matplotlib"` produces `ImportError: No module named functools_lru_cache`

Comment: @KrunalSonparate I solved the *functools_lru_cache_ issue* by installing the *functools32* package ( `pip install functools32` ).

Comment: @G.Kaklam.: I am still facing the same problem even after `pip install functools32` although functools32 is successfully installed.

Answer (score 8):

I hit this issue today due to a bad dependency.

If you have both `backports.shutil_get_terminal_size` and
`backports.functools_lru_cache` installed, you can encounter this.

Matplotlib has a brittle workaround for a cyclic import:

```
# cbook must import matplotlib only within function
# definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
from . import cbook
```

Until [PR #10483](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10483),
matplotlib dependended on `backports.functools_lru_cache`.

However, ipython depends on `backports.shutil_get_terminal_size`, and
[that package doesn't set up a namespace package
properly](https://github.com/chrippa/backports.shutil_get_terminal_size/issues/15).

If you have this problem, you'll see these symptoms:

```
>>> import backports
<module 'backports.shutil_get_terminal_size' from '/Users/whughes/miniconda2/envs/scratch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/backports/shutil_get_terminal_size/__init__.pyc'>
>>> >import backports.functools_lru_cache
ImportError: No module named functools_lru_cache
```

The problem with `backports.shutil_get_terminal_size` is that **it
doesn't define a namespace package, so it breaks any other
`backports.foo` packages**.

Reinstalling matplotlib fixes this because it changes the order in
`sys.path`, putting `backports.functools_lru_cache` first, and that
package defines a proper namespace.

You can also fix this by reinstalling `backports.shutil_get_terminal_size`.

Comment: @Wlifred : I tried your way and I am still facing the porblem of `cbook` means reinstalling backports.shutil_get_terminal_size` or `backports` or `functools32` etc. Nothing is working. Would you suggest me any other ideas...Thanks

Comment: Install matplotlib 2.0.0 using `pip install matplotlib==2.0.2` as per the answer posted [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49335954/7488168) will resolve the error

Answer (score 4):

I solve the problem uninstalling matplotpli and reinstalling without **pip**:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

Thanks to [this README.html](https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc/chapter_15/README.html).

Comment: This actually worked for me while the other options did not.

Answer (score 3):

My experience is to be careful about the version of matplotlib. Today the latest version is 3.3 and has this issue. So I specify the previous version that worked for me:

```
pip install matplotlib==3.2.2
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

just sharing my experience, I was trying to run Python code (2.7) making use of matplotlib. The code is running inside a docker container based on a Debian 10 image.

In the end I based the solution on the answers here, but there was a small caveat. I had to do the actions in the following order:

1. Install the rest of the requirements
2. Install matplotlib (no need to specify a version in my case, 2.2.5 was installed by pip)
3. Install arrow
4. Uninstall backports.functools_lru_cache
5. Install backports.functools_lru_cache version 1.2.1

The code on the dockerfile is as it follows:

```
RUN pip2 install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip2 install matplotlib
RUN pip2 install arrow
RUN pip2 uninstall -y backports.functools_lru_cache
RUN pip2 install backports.functools_lru_cache==1.2.1
```

You can find the whole project on github: https://github.com/n3if/irassh.git

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib`
and delete `__init__.py`
if there are more than one of those files, delete all of them... It will work.
For your confidence save them somewhere else first :)
see your error message, the directory is shown, the file is the init constructor written there

Answer (score -1):

**working...**

```
pip install --user matplotlib==2.0.2
```