# python 2.7 functools_lru_cache does not import although installed

Tags: python, matplotlib, backport

When I try to import matplotlib I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
  from matplotlib.rcsetup import defaultParams, validate_backend, cycler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 29, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/fontconfig_pattern.py", line 32, in <module>
    from backports.functools_lru_cache import lru_cache
ImportError: No module named functools_lru_cache
```

backports itself imports properly. When I try to install functools manually via

```
sudo pip install backports.functools_lru_cache
```

I get info that

```
Requirement already satisfied: backports.functools_lru_cache in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Nevertheless when i try to

```
import backports.functools_lru_cache
```

I get info that

```
ImportError: No module named functools_lru_cache
```

System info
Ubuntu 16
Python 2.7.12
Pip 9.0.1

Answer (score 40):

If someone is still having that problem and reinstalling backports.functools_lru_cache do not work in his case, as it was in my case, then probably installing older version of matplotlib would work. For example:

```
pip install matplotlib==2.0.2
```

Problem occurred for version 2.2.0, I switched to 2.0.2 and it is working now. I did not check other versions.

Comment: I had the same problem after updating Ubuntu to 18.04. This answer solved it for me. Note: I also had to uninstall matplotlib before via pip: `pip uninstall matplotlib`

Comment: There should not be any reason for downgrading matplotlib. If someone thinks there is an issue with matplotlib, better inform the developpers about it. However, seen from the other answers here this problem should be solvable by getting the environment into which matplotlib is installed correctly set up.

Comment: This works like a charm. It also solves the mysterious import error of 'cbook' ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623376/importerror-cannot-import-name-cbook ).

Comment: This worked! thanks a lot! I am trying to figure out the problem for more than an hour. Reinstalling my python, messing with the files on the lib/site-packages folder.

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9578#issuecomment-339479995

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem but I fixed it.

Uninstall first

```
pip uninstall backports.functools_lru_cache
```

and then re-install it.

```
pip install backports.functools_lru_cache
```

Now I'm able to import matplotlib. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. The uninstall/installation of backports.functools_lru_cache did not help. I am using Ubuntu 16.04, Python 27, pip 9.0.1, too)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7.14 and pip 9.0.1. It worked for me.

Comment: @enobufs were you able to solve the issue, I am facing the same.

Comment: @saharudra Yes, for my situation. See my post below.

Comment: @enobufs I did try that but of no use. I uninstalled matplotlib, even uninstalled python2.7 and started from scratch but of no use.

Comment: Did you try installing using anaconda?

Comment: for Python2.7 it does not help, try `from backports.functools_lru_cache import lru_cache`

Answer (score 20):

Install arrow using:

```
pip install arrow==0.12.0
```

fixed this issue for me

Comment: Interesting... this just worked for me.  It resulted in uninstalling `backports.functools-lru-cache-1.5` and then installing `backports.functools-lru-cache-1.2.1`.  What's not obvious to me is why this fixes anything.. in an interactive session the import worked fine with version 1.5.

Comment: Woo, magic! that works for me, with Python 2.7.16 and resulted in downgrade to   *backports.functools_lru_cache==1.2.1*

Answer (score 14):

The pip command was actually the pip3, and the "ImportError" was happening when I used python (2.7).

```
pip2 uninstall backports.functools_lru_cache
```

then,

```
pip2 install backports.functools_lru_cache
```

fixed my problem.

Comment: This worked for me, perhaps pip being pip3 is a new thing

Answer (score 9):

You have to check what is **the import path** of **backports** package:

```
import backports
print('Backports Path: {0}'.format(backports.__path__))
```

**1. The import path is the main python path** ( the case of Matimath's question)

```
pip uninstall backports.functools_lru_cache   (this will uninstall it from /usr/local/)
pip install backports.functools_lru_cache
```

**2. The import path is the local usr dir** (~/.local/, or %APPDATA%\Python for windows)

```
pip uninstall backports.functools_lru_cache 
pip install --user backports.functools_lru_cache
```

Use **pip2** command for python2.

The reason for this inconsistency is that the import path of backports package might have been changed during another module/package installation (eg. from  backports.configparser module) - see here for more details:
https://bugs.python.org/issue31741

Comment: The ''--user'' is exactly what is needed in a virtualenv

Answer (score 7):

Following from [Aditya Jain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52006664/3662499),

```
[python -m] pip uninstall backports.functools_lru_cache
[python -m] pip install backports.functools_lru_cache==1.2.1
```

which will avoid installing `arrow` merely to downgrade `functools_lru_cache`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and my solution was;

- Download whl file from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backports.functools_lru_cache/1.3
- pip install

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by removing the excessive matplotlib packages. I found out that when importing matplotlib it was attempting to `import backports.functools_lru_cache` and there it was throwing the `Importerror`.

I realized that I had different matplotlib packages in many locations:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/
```

I removed the site-packages one. I left the dist-packages one intact.

Then I ran the following commands in python:

```
matplotlib.get_configdir()
matplotlib.get_cachedir()
```

and I removed the matplotlib packages in the output paths of these commands.

Then I removed the matplotlib in my virtualenvironment:

```
mv /home/username/virtualenvironment/lib/python2.7/matplotlib* /tmp
```

Finally I removed the one in the .local folder:

```
mv /home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/matplotlib* /tmp
```

Now importing matplotlib works fine. So when I run in python:

```
matplotlib.__file__
```

it returns

```
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc'
```

Now it does not throw error anymore when `import backports.functools_lru_cache`

Answer (score 2):

You are using pyhton 2. try to use pip2 instead:

- pip2 uninstall matplotlib
- sudo apt-get autoremove python-matplotlib
- sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib

Answer (score 2):

If you're experiencing this issue on Ubuntu 18.x (and maybe other versions): it is caused by [this Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1812589). The problem is in the Ubuntu package `python-configparser` which is installed as a dependence of `python-pip`. It contains **empty** `__init__` file

`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports/__init__.py`

Hence, pip modules installed to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports` are simply **ignored**. As soon as this bug is not fixed yet, the easiest way to fix this is to **remove** this package:

```
sudo apt remove python-configparser
```

It does not any harm to any of your `backports` modules installed by pip (since they are in another folder), and this is much safer than version downgrade.

See also [this pip issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6149) with similar problem around `backports` module.

Comment: This solved the same problem on my raspberry pi.

Comment: It solved me the problem on Raspberry Pi too, while I was trying to play with BeautifulSoup4 using CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, re-installation of backports.functools_lru_cache resolved the issue

Comment: Please try adding an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Also meet this issue on Ubuntu 16.
Uninstall & reinstall not work for me.

My solution is reinstall from apt.

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
sudo apt-get autoremove python-matplotlib
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Ubuntu 18.04.

```
sudo pip2 uninstall backports.functools-lru-cache
sudo apt install python-backports.functools-lru-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
from backports.functools_lru_cache import lru_cache
```

Comment: This is giving following error on Ubuntu 18:
'''ImportError: No module named functools_lru_cache'''