# python 3.6 matplotlib no longer works in Python: ImportError: No module named functools_lru_cache

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Matplotlib suddenly stopped working in Python. I have updated several packages in IPython, where matplotlib still works, however in Python it does not import anymore. I would like to stress that am working in Python 3.6 (in PyCharm IDE).

This is the message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/brouw/Python/BatchAnalysis/Test.py", line 1, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "C:\Users\brouw\Anaconda3\envs\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 131, in <module>
from matplotlib.rcsetup import defaultParams, validate_backend, cycler
File "C:\Users\brouw\Anaconda3\envs\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 29, in <module>
from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
File "C:\Users\brouw\Anaconda3\envs\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\fontconfig_pattern.py", line 28, in <module>
from backports.functools_lru_cache import lru_cache

ImportError: No module named functools_lru_cache
```

I see online that the problem is quite frequent in Python 2.7, and is solved by downgrading matplotlib to a previous version, for instance here: [python 2.7 functools_lru_cache does not import although installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179433/python-2-7-functools-lru-cache-does-not-import-although-installed)

None of this seems to work for me. Hopefully someone can help. I apologize if I'm not using the right terminology (Python, IPython, etc.)

Thank you

edit: changed Python 3.5 --> 3.6

Comment: Which version of `backports.functools_lru_cache` and `matplotlib` are in use here? How did you (re)install them?

Comment: I am currently using 'matplotlib' version 2.0.2 (downgraded since it was suggested in some other posts, and 'backports.functools_lru_cache' version 1.5. I (re)installed them using pip. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: If you use python 3, you might just use matplotlib 3, which does not even depend on `backports.functools_lru_cache`.

Comment: That may sound sloppy, but I'm using python 3.5 with latest `matplotlib`, yet having no problem importing. Generally, I think there are several options you can try: 1.) update all other packages; 2.) update the python environment; 3.) try another IDE

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I did not manage to resolve this issue easily. I found traces of Python 2.7 on my machine, even though I have never had that installed. I deleted everything, installed Python 3.7 (through Anaconda) and created a new virtual environment for PyCharm. That fixed it.

Comment: You may have had a corrupted matplotlib install. This error should not happen in any version.

Comment: Might have been. Thanks for the help guys!