# R-markdown: the python-logging package seems to cause the problem

Tags: python, virtualenv, r-markdown

I am facing a strange problem which I could track down to the python `logging` package. Let me shortly explain what I want to do: the goal is to create html reports with python. I am using the R [rmarkdown](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rmarkdown) package which runs python code trough [reticulate](https://cran.r-project.org/package=reticulate) using a local virtualenv.

**The Problem**:
As soon as I install the python `logging` package rmarkdown runs into a problem when loading `matplotlib`. I have written a small test script to reproduce the example.

My system:

- Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
- Python 2.7.15rc1

Test "1" script (without `logging`):

- Create a new virtualenv (`venv`).
- Use `venv/bin/pip` to install `matplotlib`.
- Run `reticulate::import` (at the end via `rmarkdown::render`).

Test "2" script (with `logging`):

- Create a new virtualenv (`venv`).
- *In addition to the first test*: install `logging` via `venv/bin/pip`.
- Use `venv/bin/pip` to install `matplotlib`.
- Run `reticulate::import` (at the end via `rmarkdown::render`).

The modules installed (virtualenv):

```
backports.functools-lru-cache 1.5    
cycler                        0.10.0 
kiwisolver                    1.0.1  
logging                       0.4.9.6 <- only for "test 2"
matplotlib                    2.2.3  
numpy                         1.15.1 
pip                           18.0   
pkg-resources                 0.0.0  
pyparsing                     2.2.0  
python-dateutil               2.7.3  
pytz                          2018.5 
setuptools                    40.2.0 
six                           1.11.0 
subprocess32                  3.5.2  
wheel                         0.31.1
```

The system site packages do have the same module version.

**Results**:
All tests from *test 1 (without `logging`)* work nicely.
The tests from *test 2 (with `loging`)* fail when using the virtualenv. When calling `rmarkdown::render` (see below), when using the system python installation (not virtualenv) they work nice as well.

There seem to be something strange with `reticulate` when `logging` is installed in a virtualenenv.

**The output of the test script (see below)**:

The full output including the error:

```
 ----------- no logging package installed ------------
Module(matplotlib)
Module(matplotlib)
 --------- with logging package installed ------------
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NullHandler'

Detailed traceback: 
  File "/home/retos/Downloads/venvtest/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 168, in <module>
    _log.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
Calls: <Anonymous> -> py_module_import -> .Call
Execution halted
Module(matplotlib)
```

The `Module(matplotlib)` output is the success message of loading the module via `reticulate::import`. As one can see only the one test fails where the virtualenv is used with installed `logging` python module.

Anyone having an idea what could case these problems? I spent quite some time to identify the source of the error, but I am kind of lost now ...

**Test script to reproduce the error**:

Here is a small bash/shell script to reproduce my tests.

```
#!/bin/bash
# New virtual environment and install matplotlib
echo " ----------- no logging package installed ------------"
if [ -d venv ] ; then rm -rf venv ; fi
virtualenv venv &>/dev/null > /dev/null
venv/bin/pip install matplotlib > /dev/null

# Print installed packages
Rscript -e "reticulate::use_python('venv/bin/python'); reticulate::import('matplotlib')"
Rscript -e "reticulate::import('matplotlib')"

# New virtual environment and install logging and matplotlib
echo " --------- with logging package installed ------------"
if [ -d venv ] ; then rm -rf venv ; fi
virtualenv venv > /dev/null
venv/bin/pip install logging > /dev/null
venv/bin/pip install matplotlib > /dev/null

# Print installed packages
Rscript -e "reticulate::use_python('venv/bin/python'); reticulate::import('matplotlib')"
Rscript -e "reticulate::import('matplotlib')"
```

I first thought it is related to the problem "[ImportError: cannot import name cbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623376/importerror-cannot-import-name-cbook)" but the solution there did not work.

May thanks in advance!
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging [became](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html) a standard module included in Python library in version 2.3. You must not install it from PyPI. Remove it ASAP:

```
pip uninstall logging
```