# Jupyter ImportError: cannot import name cbook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am working on jupyter and python 2. When I try to use this command
          
`from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`

in jupyter notebook it shoes this error

```
     ImportError                               Traceback (most recent      call last)
<ipython-input-4-99ba79ecbbfb> in <module>()
----> 1 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

/home/adarsh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in <module>()
    124 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    125 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 126 from . import cbook
    127 from matplotlib.cbook import (
    128     _backports, mplDeprecation, dedent, get_label, sanitize_sequence)

ImportError: cannot import name cbook
```

I use ubuntu

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623376/importerror-cannot-import-name-cbook).

Answer (score 2):

Try updating matplotlib

```
python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

If this doesn't work, try uninstalling and reinstalling it

```
python -m pip uninstall matplotlib
```

then

```
python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

Let me know if this fixes it.

Comment: Sadly, even after doing these I'm still getting the same errors.

Answer (score -1):

my simple advice, create a virtual environment in python and there install matplotlib.

and please shift to python3 or else you will get less answers of your problems. try using spyder or pycharm more.

try uninstalling matplotlib and six.
then

```
conda install six=1.10.0
conda install matplotlib=2.0.2
```

may this works. don't tell you don't use anaconda.