# Cannot import name cbook in jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, importerror

I have matplotlib-2.2.3 installed. When I used matplotlib in jupyter, it throws the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name cbook in jupyter

All is OK when I run the code in PyCharm. I used python 2.7 and I have tried many suggestions like that in [ImportError: cannot import name cbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623376/importerror-cannot-import-name-cbook) but none worked.

I finally found the solution that downgrade the matplotlib and six, and that solves my question.

```
pip install six==1.10.0
pip install matplotlib==2.0.2
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50684845/4124317) should work.